# Exporting a Nested Dictionary as a Data Frame

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, nested, export-to-excel

I have seen some posts about exporting nested dictionaries but what I am trying is to export a nested dictionary using specifically the deepest level of each nested dictionary and bring it to the forefront.

Trying to make a program with the intent of creating an Excel spreadsheet to help players keep track of items in their RPG save file. To do this, I have gathered a dictionary of data points that will track a variety of the in-game items and in relation to a character level.

I'm trying to find a means of exporting a nested dictionary in a method that will make it something that can be exported into Excel.

To use an example of the format of the dictionary's values:

```
dict = [{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'A',
    'class': '1',
    'item_details': [
        {'level': 1,
         'item': 'item A',
         'quantity': 5},
        {'level': 3,
         'item': 'item A',
         'quantity': 5},
        {'level': 3,
         'item': 'item C',
         'quantity': 5}
    ]
},
{
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'B',
    'class': '2',
    'item_details': [
        {'level': 1,
         'item': 'item B',
         'quantity': 2},
        {'level': 2,
         'item': 'item D',
         'quantity': 10}
    ]
},

{
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'B',
    'class': '3'
}]
```

For my purposes, I am looking for a way to export this in a manner kind of similar to encoding data, where it would extract the item details where it finds them and leave them blank otherwise. The data frame after exporting would look something like this:

```
id  name    class   level_1 item_1  quantity_1  level_2 item_2  quantity_2  level_2 item_2  quantity_2
1      A    1       1       item A  5           3       item A  5             3     item C  5
2      B    2       1       item B  2           2       item D  10          
3      B    3
```

I believe that a pivot table is also possible. What is important is that I need to find some way to access each item inside item_details instead of all of them being localized in a single cell. Once I can get the program that extracts the data necessary and exports all the key data into their own cells, I can probably manage something from there.

The exported data frame doesn't necessarily need to look nice, since after being exported it will be used to create a more streamlined interface.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use `dict` as a variable name.** Here I've used `data`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(x, 'item_details', ['id', 'name', 'class']) 
                    if 'item_details' in x
                    else pd.json_normalize(x) 
                    for x in data])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   level    item  quantity id name class
0    1.0  item A       5.0  1    A     1
1    3.0  item A       5.0  1    A     1
2    3.0  item C       5.0  1    A     1
0    1.0  item B       2.0  2    B     2
1    2.0  item D      10.0  2    B     2
0    NaN     NaN       NaN  3    B     3
```

I'm not sure I understand the format of what you've suggested~

Comment: My bad, I was using a filler value just because it isn't the actual code, it's a simplified version just to get the main purpose of the question in. This seems to work perfectly well for what I need, thanks! There are multiple different types of items but I can certainly work with this and make a multi-page spreadsheet.